# javax.ejb.EJBException: JBAS014516: Failed to acquire a permit within 5 MINUTES- Unable to reproduce in testing region by load runner

Tags: jboss, ejb, loadrunner

We have issue in production while opening document by multiple users at same time.[Refer below trace]

```
    ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (http-/xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx-xxx) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component xxxxxx for method public abstract java.lang.String com.xxxxxxx.xxx.ejb.services.encryptionfile.xxxxxx.xxxxxx(java.lang.String): javax.ejb.EJBException: JBAS014516: Failed to acquire a permit within 5 MINUTES
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.pool.strictmax.StrictMaxPool.get(StrictMaxPool.java:109) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:278) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:330) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:242) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
```

I've tried to reproduce error at performance region. Initially I got Java heap space issue which was later resolved by increasing the heap size at Jboss config file.

However, I wasn't able to reproduce the actual prod error at testing region via Load runner [ 150 concurrent user hit].

1. Does anybody know "How we reproduce this error in testing region by Load runner.
2. This error is occured when the configured EJB pool is exhausted - means that all EJBs are currently "in use" (=processing), does anybody know how we check EJB pool size or bean so that we would able to reproduce the issue.

Do let me know if more information required about scenario and error?

Thanks,
perftest

Answer (score 0):

To monitor EJB pool, enable pool statistics using CLI

> /subsystem=ejb3:write-attribute(name=enable-statistics, value=true)

and then run below command

> /deployment=xxxx.ear/subdeployment=xx-ejb.jar/subsystem=ejb3/stateless-session-bean=HelloBean:read-resource(include-runtime=true)

To over come this issue, you need to increase `max-pool-size`,

> strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20"
>   instance-acquisition-timeout="5"
>   instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved by increasing core-thread value in server file

```
    <short-running-threads>
    <core-threads count="150"/>
    <queue-length count="150"/>
    <max-threads count="150"/>
    <keep-alive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
    </short-running-threads>
    <long-running-threads>
    <core-threads count="150"/>
    <queue-length count="150"/>
    <max-threads count="150"/>
    <keep alive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
    </long-running-threads>
```

Increased value from 50 to 150

Comment: Depending on the concrete situation, this may solve the problem (although it's rather max-threads than core-threads). But in other cases this exact measure may also worsen the situation. The first is true if beans are busy because they are waiting for a thread in the pool. But increasing the number of threads that request a bean from the pool is not helpful at all.